# Get the selected Rows from a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I am adding those rows  which are selected by user in "Items Found" grid ( left hand side of screen shot) to "Items selected" grid ( right hand side of screen shot) whenever the user clicks "Add To Cart" button.

The screen shot: [link http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/3015/datagridview.jpg](http://img856.imageshack.us/img856/3015/datagridview.jpg).

The Search Button brings the list of books from the Search Service.
Which I display in itemsFoundList which is DataGridView.

```
private void searchButton_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    itemsFoundList.Columns.Clear ();
    string[] list = searchServiceClient.BookSearch ( getBookName.Text, getAuthorName.Text );
    itemsFoundList.Columns.Add ( "Items", "Items found:" );
    displayToGrid ( itemsFoundList, list );
}
```

Now I am not getting how to add the selected rows to cartList(which is a DataGridView).

```
private void addToCart_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    //I am not getting what to write here.
}
```

Comment: Are you in control of the searchServiceClient ?  Or is it a third-party maintained service?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that you probably have a BookID or another unique identifier that you could return in addition to the information you are returning now?

Comment: Yes. We can return the unique identifier if you want. But how does it matter here? I just want those rows selected by user to be able to display in the another grid.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First in you'll probably want to change the SelectionMode of your DataGridView to FullRowSelect.  Otherwise users will likely select cells and not rows and the code below would not work. [Though you could do something similar with Selected Cells]

Then you'll want to start with code similar to the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
   //Code to add selected row to new datagrid.
   //Important to note that dataGridView2.Rows.Add(r) will not work 
   //because each row can only belong to one data grid.  You'll have 
   //to create a new Row with the same info for an exact copy
}
```

Personally I would return the bookid as a hidden column so that it ends up being available for when you are processing the user's cart.

If you wanted to move the items from one DataGridViewRow to the other [so that they could only exist in one list at a time] you could do this.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(r);
  dataGridView2.Rows.Add(r);
}
```

Comment: "First in you'll probably want to change the SelectionMode of your DataGridView to FullRowSelect." - Made my day. :-)

Comment: Ha, that was a fun little typo, hope this worked out for you.